Trigonometry interval problem
If $\frac{3\pi}{4} < \alpha < \pi$, then
$\sqrt{\csc^2(\alpha) + 2 \cot(\alpha)}$ is equal to
a: $1+\cot(\alpha)$
b: $1-\cot(\alpha)$
c: $-1-\cot(\alpha)$
d: $-1+\cot(\alpha)$
Here is my approach: $1+\cot^2(\alpha)=\csc^2(\alpha)$
So we will get $\sqrt{(1+\cot(\alpha))^2}$. In the given interval, $\cot(\alpha) < -1$. So $1+\cot(\alpha)<0$.
So my answer is $-(1+\cot(\alpha))$, which is option C. But the given answer is D. Can anyone please provide any clue or point out if I made any mistake in taking the negative? Thank you in advance.

@JohnOmielan sorry typo.  I edited now. And posted the original question

No worries, re: the typo. Also, thanks for posting the original question. Since $\cot(\alpha)\lt -1$ within the given range, then option D gives $-1+\cot(\alpha)\lt -2$, which is not possible since $\sqrt{\csc^2(\alpha) + 2 \cot(\alpha)}$ is either not real or $\ge 0$. Thus, option D cannot be the correct answer. I got the same result as you, so it appears the source you're using has a mistake itself instead.

This question is similar to: If $\frac{3\pi}{4} < x < \pi$ then $\sqrt{\csc^2 x + 2 \cot x}$ is =?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found in the "Related" section on the RHS. Note that this also confirms that your answer, i.e., $-1-\cot(\alpha)$, is the correct answer.

Thank you so much for the link. Happy to learn.

when I tried to find why it didn't appear to me? Any Idea

It depends on what you specifically tried. If you used a site search, note it doesn't really understand math, so the other question using $x$ vs. yours using $\alpha$ is likely sufficient to keep it from being found. If you haven't yet done so, I suggest you check the math Meta FAQ How to search on this site? post. In particular, it mentions using Approach0, which is what I (and other Math SE users) frequently use to search for duplicates, with it, by default, also finding AoPS (Art of Problem Solving) questions.
